# Elasticsearch coerce false performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to enforce strict type checking using coerce is false for integer fields as follows:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "number_one": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "number_two": {
          "type": "integer",
          "coerce": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does adding `coerce: false` have any performance impact since by default coerce is set to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the [documentation of `coerce`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/coerce.html) the only difference is that the "stricter" version will not perform an implicit conversion and will return an HTTP error instead (and the document will not be added).

I do not think there is any performance impact involved. `coerce: false` will just give you more control over the dirty input data.

Hope that helps!